# Add leading zero to numeric strings containing decimal value if no leading number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, number-formatting, leading-zero

I have about 200 lines in text file

values can be like

```
$array = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'....];
```

And I am looking specific regex pattern for replace .number like '.1' or '.8'

```
 preg_replace('/\.(\d+)/','0${0}',$array[0]);
```

It's working, but for value `1.5` it's output is `10.5` and that's wrong.

Comment: Because the `1` is untouched and stays there, see the replacements here https://regex101.com/r/eIRa25/1

Comment: Can you please clarify, whether you want to replace inside the _text_ value `$array = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'....];`, or whether you _have_ an actual array, and the values that should be worked upon are the individual texts `.1`, `1.5`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your values are float or integer expressions, then you can use bluntly use "start of string followed by literal dot": ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7OduW))

```
$array = ['.1', '1.5', '0.10', '.8'];
var_export(preg_replace('/^\./', '0.', $array));
```

If you need to make sure that the dot at the start of the string is followed by a digit, you could add a lookahead: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y73jM))

```
var_export(preg_replace('/^\.(?=\d)/', '0.', $array));
```

Either way, you don't need to leverage any capture groups or backreferences.

It may be useful for you to know that `preg_replace()` will happily iterate your array on its own -- no additional loop needs to be written.

---

If you'd like to directly manipulate your txt file, just add a `m` pattern modifier so that `^` means the start of each line. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QhHXs))

```
$txt = <<<TEXT
.1
1.5
0.10
.8
TEXT;
echo preg_replace('/^\.(?=\d)/m', '0.', $txt);
```

Output:

```
0.1
1.5
0.10
0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `\.(\d+)` will get a partial match in `1.5` and matches `.5`

Then the replacement will be the untouched `1` plus `0` plus `.5` resulting in `10.5`

You can replace the values that start with a dot, and match a single following digit `^\.\d`

If it should be the only value on the line, you can append an anchor for the end of the string as well `^\.\d+$`

```
$array = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'];
foreach($array as $a) {
    echo preg_replace('/^\.\d/','0$0', $a). PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
0.1
1.5
0.10
0.8
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/h105s)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of values similar to the one you presented, then this can be solved without regular expressions. it's easy enough to use [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php),for example `floatval('.8')` will return `0.8`. A general example is below:

```
$input = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'];
$output = array_map('floatval', $input);
print_r($output); // => Array ( [0] => 0.1 [1] => 1.5 [2] => 0.1 [3] => 0.8 )
```

Or if you need to strictly have strings:

```
$input = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'];
$output = array_map(function($item) {
    return strval(floatval($item));
}, $input);
print_r($output); // => Array ( [0] => 0.1 [1] => 1.5 [2] => 0.1 [3] => 0.8 )
```

Or a short version with support for arrow functions (PHP >= 7.4):

```
$input = ['.1','1.5','0.10','.8'];
$output = array_map(fn($item) => strval(floatval($item)), $input);
print_r($output); // => Array ( [0] => 0.1 [1] => 1.5 [2] => 0.1 [3] => 0.8 )
```

If you need to normalize such values inside the text, then you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) + `floatval`

```
$input = "Test text: .1 + 1.5 = 1.6 and 000.10 - .8 = .2";
$output = preg_replace_callback("|\d*\.\d+|", fn($item) => floatval($item[0]), $input);
print_r($output); // => "Test text: 0.1 + 1.5 = 1.6 and 0.1 - 0.8 = 0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the context before `.` char.

You can check is the `'` char is present before the `.`  + digits:

```php
preg_replace("/'\K\.\d+/",'0$0',$array[0]);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQmdWJ/1). *Details*:

- `'` -  a `'` char
- `\K` - forget the `'` matched char
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits

The `0$0` pattern replaces with `0` + the whole match value. Note the unambiguous `${0}` backreference form is only required if the backreference is followed with a literal digit, not when it is preceded with it.